# TextToSpeech onInit not firing

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I can't get TextToSpeech to work.

It seems to me that I am having trouble initialising through the onInit method, since I don't seem to be able to debug this code.  Hence, I'm wondering how I fire this programmatically.

Or maybe my environment set up is wrong.  I am running Android Studio Beta 3 min SDK 22.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    TextToSpeech tospeech;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_tree_play);
              tospeech = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {

         if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = tospeech.setLanguage(Locale.UK);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
               Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
             } 
             else {

                 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                     tospeech.speak("I am a dog",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null,null);
                 } 
                 else 
                 {
                     tospeech.speak("I am a dog", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                 }
        }

    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
    }

}

}
```

Comment: What's the status you receive in onInit?

Comment: I don't get a status as onInit doesn't fire for some reason.  Am I right in thinking that it should get called immediately as variable is initialised?

Comment: Ok, ignore the previous. Managed to enter and have speech fire. I think problem is I have an Async task running too, and perhaps this is causing an issue with the order events are fired...

Comment: I'll need to update the question.  onInit won't fire until after an asynctask has finished execution.  So, problem not with code above, but with interrelation with async code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, was nothing wrong with above code.  My issues was that I had an Async Task which would run to completion before onInit could fire.

Solution is to put the execute call for the async task into the onInit method.  That way, can guarantee that TextToSpeech variable is initialised before proceeding.